# Как удалить элемент при клике на картинку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Делаю загрузку изображений. Изображения добавляются. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать возможность удалять изображения. Спасибо
Почему-то я не могу удалить изображения таким образом

```js
const cartBlockInputFile = document.querySelectorAll('.photo-checkout__input-file');
if (cartBlockInputFile) {
    cartBlockInputFile.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            var file = event.target.files; // FileList object
            for (var i = 0, f; f = file[i]; i++) {
                // Only process image files.
                if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                    alert("Image only please....");
                }
                var reader = new FileReader();
                const inputImg = document.querySelectorAll('.photo-checkout__input-file-img');
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                const inputRemove = document.querySelectorAll('.photo-checkout__input-file-remove span');
                // Closure to capture the file information.
                reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                    return function cartBlockFileMask(e) {
                        // Render thumbnail.
                        span.className = 'preview'
                        span.innerHTML = [
                            '<div class="photo-checkout__input-file-remove _icon-close">Удалить</div>' +
                            '<img class="thumb" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" src="', e.target.result, '" />'
                        ].join('');

                        inputImg.forEach(img => {
                            img.classList.add("_active")
                            img.insertBefore(span, null);
                        });
                    };



                })(f);

                if (inputRemove) {
                    inputRemove.forEach(btn => {
                        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                            const item = btn.closest('.preview');
                            item.remove();
                            event.value = ''; // ключевая строка
                        });
                    });
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            };
        });

    });
};
```

```css
.photo-checkout__block {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.photo-checkout__input-file-img {
  display: flex;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.photo-checkout__input-file-img._active {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.photo-checkout__input-file-img span {
  position: relative;
  width: 165px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}

.photo-checkout__input-file-img span:hover .photo-checkout__input-file-remove {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.photo-checkout__input-file-img span img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.photo-checkout__input-file span {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.photo-checkout__input-file input {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 165px;
  height: 120px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.photo-checkout__input-file label {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 165px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  color: #000000;
}
.photo-checkout__input-file label::before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  color: #000000;
}
.photo-checkout__input-file-remove {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    rgba(54, 108, 217, 0.8),
    rgba(54, 108, 217, 0.8)
  );
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-checkout__block">
  <div class="photo-checkout__input-file">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="file">
    <label>Фотография<br> товара</label>
                                                            <div class="photo-checkout__input-file-img"></div>
  </div 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте передать в колбэк объект события, отследить с помощью него по какому элементу был клик, и удалить его со страницы.

```
if (inputRemove) {
    inputRemove.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const target = e.target;
            if (taget && target.classList.contains('preview')){
                target.remove();
           }
        });
    });
}
```